# The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception

Tags: c#, httpclient

То получаю эту ошибку, то нет. Как её избежать ?

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception."

Внутренние исключение
IOException:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.

```
        // Создание экземпляра класса System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.
        HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new()
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.Brotli,
            AllowAutoRedirect = true
        };

        // Создание экземпляра класса для отправки HTTP-запросов и получения HTTP-ответов 
        HttpClient httpClient = new(httpClientHandler);


        HttpRequestMessage request = new(HttpMethod.Post, "https://скрыл");

        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("скрыл", "скрыл"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("скрыл", "скрыл"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("скрыл", "скрыл"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("скрыл", "скрыл")
        });

        HttpResponseMessage response;

        try
        {
            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.WriteLog($"скрыл", e.Message);
            throw;
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что вы используете? .NET Framework (если да, то какой), или что-то новее?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ .NET 5.0

Comment: @EvgeniyZ более того, игнорируется блок catch(. Можете поделиться опытом, что тут не так ?

Comment: Такие ошибки непросто отлавливать. Вам нужно поставить какой-нибудь прокси и смотреть пролетающие запросы и долго ковырять подобные баги. Они как правило инфраструктурные, сильно завязаны на особенности конкретной сети.

Comment: @AK да, очень неприятная и я думал реально что то не так с сертификатами в которых ничего не понимаю и сутки гуглил ничего не добившись. А оказалось в 1 случае меня тупо банят спустя несколько быстрых запросов и достаточно использовать прокси с ротацией, в 2 случае просто делаю перезапросы при появлении это исключения.

Comment: В корпоративной среде не банят, но такие ошибки долго и неприятно воспроизводить. Но если у вас чужой сервис, который ограничивает количество запросов, то вам надо задуматься о троттлинге.